# Remove all HTML with Jsoup but keep the lines

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I have a `String` which contains some of the content of an e-mail, I want to remove all the HTML coding from this `String`.

This is my code at the moment:

```
public static String html2text(String html) {

   Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
   document = new Cleaner(Whitelist.basic()).clean(document);
   document.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
   document.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
   html = document.body().html();

   html = html.replaceAll("<br />", "");

   splittedStr = html.split("Geachte heer/mevrouw,");

   html = splittedStr[1];

   html = "Geachte heer/mevrouw,"+html;

   return html;
}
```

This method removes all HTML, keeps lines and most of the layout. But it will also return some `&amp;` and `nbsp;` tags, which aren't completely removed. See the output below, as you can see there are still some tags and even parts of it in the `String`. How do I get rid of these?

```
  Loonheffingen       &amp;n= bsp; Naam
 nr         in administratie         &amp;nbs= p;           meldingen
  nummer

 1          &amp;n= bsp;            = ;     0            &amp;= nbsp;           &amp;nbs= p;           1
           123456789L01
```

**Edit:**

```
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">De afgekeurde meldingen zijn opgenomen in de bijlage: Afgekeurde meldingen.</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">

<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">Wilt u zo spoedig mogelijk zorgdragen dat deze</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">meldingen gecorrigeerd worden aangeleverd?</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">mer</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">Volg &nbsp; &nbsp; Aantal verwerkt &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Aantal afgekeurde</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&nbsp;Loonheffingen &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Naam</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">nr &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; in administratie &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; meldingen</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&nbsp;nummer</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
<br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><span style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;0 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;1</span><br style="color:rgb(34,34,34);font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
```

This is a part of the HTML I am trying to parse. I want to remove all the HTML, but keep the layout of the original e-mail.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

**Solved**

```
        Document xmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(file, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        Elements spans= xmlDoc.select("span");

        for (Element link : spans) {
            String html = textPlus(link);
            System.out.println(html);
        }


 public static String textPlus(Element elem) {
    List<TextNode> textNodes = elem.textNodes();
    if (textNodes.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    // start at the first text node
    Node currentNode = textNodes.get(0);
    while (currentNode != null) {
        // append deep text of all subsequent nodes
        if (currentNode instanceof TextNode) {
            TextNode currentText = (TextNode) currentNode;
            result.append(currentText.text());
        } else if (currentNode instanceof Element) {
            Element currentElement = (Element) currentNode;
            result.append(currentElement.text());
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.nextSibling();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Code was provided as an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042367/get-the-text-in-anchors-within-text-nodes) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do this, you need to iterate through the HTML structure returned by JSoup and collate the text nodes. That way you're letting JSoup determine what's really text, and the entity codings will be handled for you (e.g. `&amp;` -> `&` etc.).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164376/how-to-extract-separate-text-nodes-with-jsoup) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One small problem, I don't know which elements I should search for. I tried to get all `span` elements, but it didn't return anything. Take a look at my post, I've edited it with a part of the HTML I am trying to parse.